# How to set SimpleMembershipProvider to require unique email?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I started a new MVC 4 application using VS 2012 and I noticed it is recommending the use of SimpleMembershipProvider.

I like the idea and all the goodies of the WebSecurity class (which helps a lot).

I'd like to be able to set the RequiresUniqueEmail property to true the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.requiresuniqueemail%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) doesn't have a suggestion on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the property `requiresUniqueEmail="true"` to the

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" 
         type="whatever your assembly name is"
         ... 
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"/>
```

tag in your web.config?  That's how it's done for the default membership provider.  I would imagine it would be the same for the Simple version (unless that feature was not implemented).

Comment: I tried that already but it throws an exception: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase. And it points to the line on the we.config where I'm adding the provider.

Comment: Perhaps this is at play:  "By design, the SimpleMembershipProvider class does not implement the full range of functionality that is possible in ASP.NET membership providers, as defined in the MembershipProvider class that is used by all ASP.NET membership providers. Some members are available in the class because they are inherited from the base class, but will throw an exception if you access them."--(from msdn docs)   You may simply need to implement a standard (default) MembershipProvider.

Comment: Yes, that is problem not implemented, even though I believe it is a very common requirement. Anyways, I read somewhere that I can use the WebSecurity class with the default/standard MembershipProvider instead. I will have to keep digging and see how can I get the best of both. thanks a lot.

Comment: Sort of, System.Web.Security is a namespace, not a class, and, yes, all of the Membership Provider classes are part of the Web.Security namespace.

Comment: I really meant WebSecurity class, on the WebMatrix.WebData namespace (see documentation at [MSDN](http://bit.ly/Ru3F1h)).